# Azure Media Services Modify stream (add images / text like twitch)

Tags: c#, .net, azure, stream, azure-media-services

I'm in the process of developing a Twitch-like application that supports Live Streaming. I would like to use Azure Media Services for this.

Looking at the [REST Api of Azure Media Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh973617.aspx) it really looks like it can handle almost all the stuff that I require, for example playing advertisements. There is just one thing I can't seem to find and I really hope someone is able to guide me into the right direction.

How am I able to 'modify' the stream in such a way that it will show images / texts on the live video stream? For example as a donation comes in at Twitch the users are presented with a question on the video for the streamer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When your Channel has Live Encoding enabled, you have a component in your pipeline that is processing video, and can manipulate it. You can signal for the Channel to insert slates and/or advertisements into the outgoing adaptive bitrate stream. Slates are still images that you can use to cover up the input live feed in certain cases (for example during a commercial break). Advertising signals, are time-synchronized signals you embed into the outgoing stream to tell the video player to take special action – such as to switch to an advertisement at the appropriate time.

Comment: Thanks sounds promising :-) I was also looking into Overlay's, still means I have to generate images from text but that's no biggy.